# Is there a toggle button bar component in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a menu (similar to Bootstrap navbar) that when a button is selected, I can swap its image. Navbar simply shows a depressed, selected state.

Just like a Flex ToggleButtonBar, only one button can be selected at a time.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap the styles of a `navbar` link, you can access its styles with:

```
#theNavbar .active {
    // your styles
}
```

That should be enough to change its appearance at your discretion.

---

If you are talking about buttons, within a `navbar` o not, you can achieve the same behaviour using:

```
#theButton.active {
    // your styles
}
```

And also you can toggle its text with:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="button" data-complete-text="finished!" >
    ...
</button>
```